# How to reindex a dataframe using two datetime variables that define a duration

Tags: python, datetime, reindex

I am trying to reindex my dataframe that has two datetime variables which define the duration. I want my dataframe to be indexed by one datetime variable incrementing by 1 minute with missing values/strings where there is no observation.

My data looks something like this

```
DMS = pandas.DataFrame({
  'ID':[1,1,2,3],
  'SentTime':['2016-01-22 14:47:05.486877', '2016-01-22 14:53:03.234377', '2016-01-22 14:45:09.434877','2016-01-22 14:48:05.486877'],
  'EndTime':['2016-01-22 14:50:10.454347', '2016-01-22 14:57:45.456877', '2016-01-22 14:56:05.456877','2016-01-22 14:52:05.486877'],
  'BinaryVariable1':[0, 1, 0, 0],
  'BinaryVariable2':[0, 0, 0, 1],
  'StringVariable':['ABC','DE','FG','XYZ']
})
```

I want this dataframe to look like

```
ID  Time    BinaryVariable1 BinaryVariable2 StringVariable
1   1/22/2016 14:45 NaN NaN NaN
1   1/22/2016 14:46 NaN NaN NaN
1   1/22/2016 14:47 0   0   ABC
1   1/22/2016 14:48 0   0   ABC
1   1/22/2016 14:49 0   0   ABC
1   1/22/2016 14:50 0   0   ABC
1   1/22/2016 14:51 NaN NaN NaN
1   1/22/2016 14:52 NaN NaN NaN
1   1/22/2016 14:53 1   0   DE
1   1/22/2016 14:54 1   0   DE
1   1/22/2016 14:55 1   0   DE
1   1/22/2016 14:56 1   0   DE
1   1/22/2016 14:57 1   0   DE
1   1/22/2016 14:58 NaN NaN NaN
1   1/22/2016 14:59 NaN NaN NaN
1   1/22/2016 15:00 NaN NaN NaN
2   1/22/2016 14:45 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:46 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:47 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:48 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:49 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:50 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:51 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:52 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:53 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:54 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:55 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:56 0   0   FG
2   1/22/2016 14:57 NaN NaN NaN
2   1/22/2016 14:58 NaN NaN NaN
2   1/22/2016 14:59 NaN NaN NaN
2   1/22/2016 15:00 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:45 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:46 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:47 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:48 0   1   XYZ
3   1/22/2016 14:49 0   1   XYZ
3   1/22/2016 14:50 0   1   XYZ
3   1/22/2016 14:51 0   1   XYZ
3   1/22/2016 14:52 0   1   XYZ
3   1/22/2016 14:53 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:54 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:55 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:56 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:57 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:58 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 14:59 NaN NaN NaN
3   1/22/2016 15:00 NaN NaN NaN
```

Any ideas? I can create index using `pandas.date_range` but I am having a challenge incorporating `EndTime` which is varying across observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always process it row by row: 1),Create an empty DataFrame `res` ; 2), pick one row of `DMS` and fill relevant row in `res` with row value; 3), loop until all rows are processed.

Here I solve it with some (maybe unnecessary) tricks.  By taking advantage of `apply` method, you don't have to iterate `DMS` yourself:

```py
DMS['SentTime'] = pd.to_datetime(DMS['SentTime']).dt.floor('60S')
DMS['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(DMS['EndTime']).dt.floor('60S')

dt_idx = pd.date_range(start=DMS['SentTime'].min(),end=DMS['EndTime'].max(),freq='60S')
# may you need '2016-01-22 15:00:00' as end insteand of DMS['EndTime'].max()
res = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([DMS['ID'].unique(),dt_idx],names=['ID','TIME']),columns=DMS.columns)

def p(x):    
    _s = pd.IndexSlice[(x['ID'],pd.DatetimeIndex(start=x['SentTime'],end=x['EndTime'],freq='60S')),:]
    res.loc[_s] = x.values
    return '**'

DMS.apply(p,axis=1)

print(res)
```